# Change my terminal's character set in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, perl, greek

I would like to process with perl some files in Greek in which the character encoding is ***Greek (ISO-8859-7)*** but my terminal doesn't support such an encoding. Can I add it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will update this answer if you add more details about what exactly you need to do. On my system, using either `terminator` or `gnome-terminal` on a UTF-8 encoded Greek text file, I can use Perl to parse Greek:

```
$ cat test
Με λένε Μαρία
Με λένε Πόπη
Με λένε Κίτσο

$ file test
test: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ perl -ne 'print if /Πόπη/' test
Με λένε Πόπη
```

---

You can change the encoding of `gnome-terminal` like this:

[image]

Find and activate UTF-8. Then, you can change the encoding of your file using `iconv`:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-7 -t utf8  text.txt > new_text.txt
```

Comment: i made it!!!i importet on my terminal the character encoding Greek (ISO-8859-7) and it workes fine!!! thnx again very usefull help!!!!